# Телеграмм бот "сбрасывает авторизацию"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть телеграмм бот который периодично на стороне клиента останавливается. Т.е после такой остановки любое действие с ботом на стороне клиента необходимо начать с /start. В логе бота нет никакой информации в период когда у клиента остановился бот. При такой остановке пропадает ReplyKeyboardMarkup и появляется только после отправки /start.
Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Если бот останавливается на стороне клиента, то, вероятно, он теряет связь с сервером Telegram

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду Бот теряет связь или клиент? Если клиент то почему к примеру работают остальные боты.